# grep line and line after into one line

Tags: bash, grep

I have text file with lots of information. I'm interested in getting only aliases. 
All alias and the port information are separated by a space, each port is separated by semicolon.

This command..

```
cat ~/Desktop/brocade_output.txt  |grep -A1 alias
```

Gives me this output. All aliases start with a_ prefix.

```
>  alias:   a_computer_1    
        40:01:00:00:ab:00:00:aj; 60:01:00:0e:1e:d0:b5:fd
--
 alias: a_helpdesk  
        41:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9e; 81:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9f
--
 alias: a_library   
        91:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9g; 91:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9g
--
```

Desired output

```
a_computer_1 40:01:00:00:ab:00:00:aj 60:01:00:0e:1e:d0:b5:fd
a_helpdesk 41:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9e 81:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9f
a_library 91:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9g 91:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9g
```

Comment: It's basically what's on the "Output" section. Just a much bigger file.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: If you print context lines grep will always introduce a separator when printing context lines. Although you can suppress the separator, grep does not reformat content. I agree with Mad Physicist. This is better done with sed, awk, or even perl.

Comment: Thanks, Im open to sed or awk suggestions. Not married to grep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '/alias/ {f=$2;next} f{$1=$1; print f, $0; f=0 }' file
a_computer_1 40:01:00:00:ab:00:00:aj; 60:01:00:0e:1e:d0:b5:fd
a_helpdesk 41:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9e; 81:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9f
a_library 91:00:00:24:fh:5c:99:9g; 91:00:00:24:ff:5c:48:9g
```

Explained:

- `/alias/ {f=$2;next}` when `alias` in record, `f` equals second field
- `f{$1=$1; print f, $0; f=0 }` when `f`set, print it and the "next record"

Comment: Now we cooking with gas. Still has the semicolon but I can find another way to remove it.

Comment: `++` for you know why!

Comment: Oh there was a semicolon, missed that one. Add a `sub(/;/,"")` before the `$1=$1`.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/alias:/N;{s/.*\(a_[^ ]* \)[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1\2/p;}' file
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, I also updated the question to provide a little more information. "sed: 1: "/alias:/N;{s/.*\(a_comp ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -A1 alias ~/Desktop/brocade_output.txt | cut -f2- -d":"
```

My understanding is you want the part of the line that follows the first `:`, so using `:` as the delimiter for `cut` and taking all fields starting at 2 should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I first posted with "-f1-" instead of "-f2", it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in Perl with a few more characters:

```
perl -ane 'if (/alias/){$_=<>; s/^\s*//; print "$F[1] $_"}' file
```

These command-line options are used:
 - `-n` loop around each line of the input file
 - `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array
 - `-e` execute the perl code

`/alias/` matches the current line
`$F[1]` is the second element in `@F`
`$_=<>` assigns the `$_` default variable to the next line from the input file
`s/^\s*//` removes the leading spaces from `$_`